# MemoryStream throws ObjectDisposedException when trying to access it in its own using statement

Tags: c#, stream, using, memorystream, objectdisposedexception

I'm trying to use streams to progressively display a jpeg as it loads. This used to work fine, but this morning I tried running my code and now no images can be loaded because of this error. The relevant code is as follows:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
using (Stream streamRemote = wc.OpenRead(url))
using (Stream streamLocal = new MemoryStream((int)fileSize))
{
    int byteSize = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileSize];

    while ((byteSize = streamRemote.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        streamLocal.Write(buffer, 0, byteSize); // Error is here.
        bytesDownloaded += byteSize;

        int progressPercentage = (int)(bytesDownloaded / buffer.Length) * 100;

        if (progressPercentage % 10 == 0)
        {
            imageLoader.ReportProgress(progressPercentage, streamLocal);
        }
    }
}

// Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in mscorlib.dll
// An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
// Cannot access a closed Stream.
```

After using Console.WriteLine at the end of the that final using statement (after the while loop), I've found that the code seems to run through the loop a couple times before throwing that exception.

I don't understand why I would be trying to access a closed stream when the code is clearly happening *within* the using statement that the stream is declared in. I also don't understand why it worked the other day and doesn't now. Most of the code for this comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000212/how-can-i-display-a-progressive-jpeg-in-wpf#6001711), so the rest of my method can be found there. Mine isn't much different apart from some variable name changes and other small changes. Can anyone help fix this?

Edit: My _ProgressChanged event:

```
private void ImageLoader_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!fileFailed)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Action(delegate ()
        {
            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream stream = e.UserState as MemoryStream)
                {
                    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                    bmp.BeginInit();
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray())) bmp.StreamSource = ms;
                    bmp.EndInit();

                    img_CurrentImage.Source = bmp;
                }
            }
            // A few catch statements here - none of the exceptions here are being thrown anyway so I'll omit the catch statements
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is you `_ProgressChanged` handler identical to that shown in the other answer? I'm a bit wary of the way it's being used to "smuggle" the `MemoryStream` into another context. If it's misused in that other context, that could be the source of the issue.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's almost identical, but I'll edit it into the post anyway.

Comment: Seems like you do something with Treading in the ImageLoader_ProgressChanged. if this is a different tread, I understand the error. I am not familair with Dispatcher so see this as a possible hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I suspected, it's because you're misusing the `MemoryStream` in your `ProgressChanged` handler.

This line:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = e.UserState as MemoryStream)
```

Is taking the stream object that was passed to `ProgressChanged()` and will later on in the delegate `Dispose` of it. But that's *exactly the same* stream object that you're wondering how it got disposed inside your `DoWork` method.

That stream doesn't "belong" to the `ProgressChanged` handler. It shouldn't be disposing of it.

It's somewhat subtle, but in the linked question, the only thing that's done with the passed in stream is to access its `ToArray` method. Which you need to also be careful to do since, because `ProgressChanged` (and `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`) is asynchronous, you could easily be dealing with an already disposed object in this handler (but `ToArray` is safe to call on disposed `MemoryStream`s)

You might also consider extracting the `byte[]` array from the `MemoryStream` inside your `DoWork` method and making *that* the passed state instead of the `MemoryStream`. That would make it far less prone to misuse both now and in any future edits to this code.

Comment: Ah, this was it. Thank you!

Could you elaborate on your last paragraph a little though, please? Would I pass the byte[] array into the _ProgressChanged event and then make a new MemoryStream with that array, or what?

Comment: @Athied - in `DoWork`, have `imageLoader.ReportProgress(progressPercentage, streamLocal.ToArray());` instead. Then yes, pass that in to the existing call of `ProgressChanged` that;s creating a new `MemoryStream`.